# How Can make PyCharm's autocomplete work on django?

Tags: python, django

I am using pycharm community , I make test project on django and in template I make degree.html file.
I have the following code in degree.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>welcome to degree site of {{student_id}}</title>
</head>
<body>
{%for item in degree%}
<h4>
{{item.student_dgree}}
</h4>
<h4>
{{item.student_id}}
</h4>
{%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

I can't complete instruction like "for , endfor , .. etc"
I install django from cmd and from pycharm's terminal too using pip.

and from **File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter** I add django Package and install it

help please !

Comment: PyCharm community has no support for Django, the paid versions of PyCharm can "understand" Django (to some extent :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm Community has no built in support for Django Template language (only Pro version). You could try an Extension/Plugin like Djaneiro:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9295-djaneiro-for-pycharm

Answer (score -1):

You could look into Kite - an AI "coding assistant" that will provide helpful autocomplete features for more than just Django.

https://kite.com/

Here's the docs specific to Django for Python - https://kite.com/python/docs/django